# Mongoimort - importing date field from a CSV file

Tags: mongodb, date, csv, import

I am using mongoimport to import a CSV file which contains some date fields. The date is in 'DD.MM.YYYY' format.

I am getting below error message when trying to import the file.

> Failed: type coercion failure in document #0 for column 'ImportedDate', could not parse token '16.08.2015' to type date

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the format of your date to fit the format required for mongodb. Bellow goes an example of how to do it in python:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import numpy as np;

file = "your_file.csv"

outCsv = []
header = ['header1','header2',...,'headerN']
outCsv.append(header)

with open(file,'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        d = datetime.strptime(''.join(row['dateHeader'].rsplit(':', 1)), '%Y.%m.%d')
        iso_string = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
        tmpLine = [row['header1-value'],...,iso_string,row['headerN-value']]
        outCsv.append(tmpLine)


np.savetxt("file_to_import.csv",outCsv,delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
```

Hope my answer was helpful.